# SAPUI5 export chart as an xlsx file

Tags: javascript, excel, sapui5, export-to-excel

I have a simple chart and a button. In order to create the desired chart, I used the `sap.viz.ui5.controls.VizFrame` component.

The idea with the button is, when the user clicks on it, the chart has to be exported as an **xlsx** file.
I saw that there is the possibility to export sapui5 charts as images, but it is a requirement from my client to be exported as an **xlsx** file.

So, I'm looking for an external library or any other ideas or solutions, on the client-side, which can be used to export this chart as an **xlsx** file.

View :

```
sap.ui.jsview("app.views.chart", {
  getControllerName: function() {
    return "app.controllers.chart";
  },
  createContent: function(oController) {
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("app/model/chart.data.json");
    oController.getView().setModel(oModel);
    return new sap.m.App({
      pages: [
        new sap.m.Page({
          title: "My fourth page",
          content: [
            new sap.m.Switch({
              name: "Switch label",
              state: true,
              change: oController.onChange
            }),
            new sap.viz.ui5.controls.VizFrame("cars-chart-id", {
              width: "100%",
              height: "100%",
              uiConfig: {
                applicationSet: "fiori"
              },
              vizType: "bar",
              vizProperties: {
                plotArea: {
                  colorPalette: d3.scale.category20().range(),
                  dataLabel: {
                    visible: true
                  }
                }
              },
              dataset: new sap.viz.ui5.data.FlattenedDataset({
                dimensions: [{
                  axis: 1,
                  name: "Model",
                  value: "{Model}"
                }],
                measures: [{
                  name: "Nr Cars",
                  value: "{Value}"
                }]
              }).bindData("/", null, null, []),
              feeds: [
                new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({
                  'uid': "categoryAxis",
                  'type': "Dimension",
                  'values': ["Model"]
                }),
                new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({
                  'uid': "valueAxis",
                  'type': "Measure",
                  'values': ["Nr Cars"]
                })
              ]
            })
          ]
        })
      ]
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: In SAPUI5 table has the export functionality, you can use the same functionality. You can create a dummy table with the same graph model and export to excel.

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but I also need the chart to be visible in Excel, not only the chart model data in table format. The idea is to see, the same or a similar chart, in Excel as it is on the web page.